# How to get public IP address in Ubuntu

Tags: ip-address

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I tried to get my public IP address in command prompt. But, it shows only local ip. Is there any way to get public ip from command line.

Answer (score 10):

you can also use the following by AWS:

```
curl checkip.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have an external service provide your external IP.

```
curl ident.me
```

Comment: Note that this will return either IPv4 or IPv6; if you want IPv4 specifically, use v4.ident.me. We also support HTTPS and a host of other protocols, docs @ https://api.ident.me

Answer (score 0):

> curl -s icanhazip.com

this will work too

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip

Answer (score -1):

Yet another way is the following:
`curl -s httpbin.org/ip | tr -d '"\{\} ' | sed '/^$/d' | cut -d: -f2`